# css diagonal line rotate with text

Tags: html, css

I have a diagonal line in my website and some text in middle of it, I want to rotate the text based on how the diagonal line is. The problem is that the line is responsive and when I put a fixed rotate() function it works only for one resolution

like this:

```
rotate(-11deg) on 324x564 resolution
```

[324x564](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v9IQ.png)

```
rotate(-11deg) on 980x564 resolution
```

[980x564](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPNC.png)

On the first image the rotate works well but on the second, no. How can I fix this ? Apart from making media queries for all different resolutions

Divider line html code:

```
<div class="divider1">
    <h2>TEST</h2>
</div>
```

Divider line css code:

```
    .divider {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 0 0;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.divider1 {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.divider1 h2 {
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 4rem;
    rotate(-11deg);
}


.divider1:before {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
    margin-top: -70px;
    content: '';
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 7rem 100vw;
    border-color: transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) transparent;
}

.divider1:after {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    content: '';
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 7rem 100vw;
    border-color: transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) transparent;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
    transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

Comment: Insert your code so we can see the problem.

Comment: Please show us your attempt (full code) or a link to the demo

Comment: Is it possible for you to merge the text and the background into a single image so they will rotate together?

Comment: @RussJ The diagonal line is one central div -non rotated and two triangles positioned so it looks like a diagonal line

Comment: Therein lies your issue. Those triangles are going to appear differently when the aspect ratio of your display changes, as you have indicated, you have two different resolutions and ratios. You may have to employ CSS viewport to customize your code for differing resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

As you've got it set up, it's likely that the triangles are getting distorted based on the differing aspect ratios of your displays while the rotation remains constant across them. You're probably going to have to apply some viewport or media queries in your background CSS to compensate for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this differently by adding a white background to the rotated element so that the rotation will always match the diagonal line and use a gradient on the main container with the same angle too:

```css
.divider {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-11deg, red 50%, blue 0);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 -50px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-11deg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
```

You can also move the white coloration inside the gradient:

```css
.divider {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-11deg, 
    red calc(50% - 42px),#fff calc(50% - 40px), 
    #fff calc(50% + 40px),blue calc(50% + 42px));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 -50px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-11deg);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">
  <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
```